# R programming data set

Tags: r

I loaded mtcars dataset in R program.I saw a question regarding that

1) find the average of mpg (miles per gallon of all automatic tranmission cars

That is you have to check am column in mt cars data set and you have two values 0 for manual tranmission and 1 for automatic transmission and you have to first filter values with 1 and later you need to get the corresponding values for mpg column and find the mean for that

for reference data set of mtcar is listed below:

```
> mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

for any other help if needed go to search (near that plot interface where graph are visible) and type mtcars.

Comment: @akrun it should be `aggregate(mpg~am, mtcars, mean)`. He wants to group by type of transmission, not the number of cylinders. Get to learn so much from your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`which()` does the filtering here and gives you the rows which satisfy the desired condition. Then simply take `mean()` of the column `mpg` for these rows, which correspond to automatic transmission.

```
mean(mtcars$mpg[which(mtcars$am==1)])
#[1] 24.39231
```

As suggested in the comment by @Florian, another shorter form exist to achieve the same result. We can index arrays by both index or boolean, so you can also try:

```
mean(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])
#[1] 24.39231
```

Comment: Note that you can index arrays by both index or boolean, so `mean(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$am==1])` is a slightly shorter alternative.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
library(Hmisc)
summarize(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$am,mean)

#summarize(variable to be summarized, grouping variable, function to apply)
```

Answer (score 0):

another one. using attach so you dont have to write mtcars$ everytime you refer to a variable.

```
attach(mtcars)
> mean(mtcars[am==1,"mpg"])
[1] 24.39231
> mean(mtcars[am==0,"mpg"])
[1] 17.14737
```